# Stanford Parser out of memory

Tags: java, python, ubuntu, jvm, stanford-nlp

I am trying to run Stanford parser in Ubuntu using python code. My text file is of 500 Mb which i am trying to parse.I have a RAM of 32GB. I am increasing the JVM size, but i don't whether it is actually increasing or not because every-time i am getting this error. Please help me out

```
WARNING!! OUT OF MEMORY! THERE WAS NOT ENOUGH  ***
***  MEMORY TO RUN ALL PARSERS.  EITHER GIVE THE    ***
***  JVM MORE MEMORY, SET THE MAXIMUM SENTENCE      ***
***  LENGTH WITH -maxLength, OR PERHAPS YOU ARE     ***
***  HAPPY TO HAVE THE PARSER FALL BACK TO USING    ***
***  A SIMPLER PARSER FOR VERY LONG SENTENCES.      ***
Sentence has no parse using PCFG grammar (or no PCFG fallback).  Skipping...
Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.NoSuchParseException
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParserQuery.getBestParse(LexicalizedParserQuery.java:398)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParserQuery.getBestParse(LexicalizedParserQuery.java:370)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ParseFiles.processResults(ParseFiles.java:271)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ParseFiles.parseFiles(ParseFiles.java:215)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ParseFiles.parseFiles(ParseFiles.java:74)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.main(LexicalizedParser.java:1513)
```

Comment: How are you feeding the file to the parser?  As a file or as a huge string containing the contents?

Comment: huge strings @TritonMan

Comment: Right, you need to either pass in a filename or a stream or something.  If you load the entire file into a string, a 500MB file, that will take way too much RAM.

Comment: @TritonMan  Ram is not a problem.I have 32 Gb Ram. Can you tell me how can i increase the size of JVM for stanford parser.?

Comment: -Xmx16G as a JVM argument maybe? It will only work of course if you are on a 64bit JVM

Comment: I have 32bit JVM. By the way my stanford parser is embedded in python code. So where to input -Xmx command

Comment: A 32bit JVM can only handle about 1.5 GB or RAM when starting it up, you need either 64-bit JVM or a different solution.  You pass it on the command line, for instance: java -Xmx1024m

Comment: If you use a 64-bit JVM, you can set the heap size to `-Xmx30G` and use all the memory of the machine. A 32-bit JVM cannot address all the memory you have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should divide the text file into small pieces and give them to the parser one at a time. Since the parser creates an in-memory representation for a whole "document" it is given at a time (which is orders of magnitude bigger than the document on disk), it is a very bad idea to try to give it a 500 MB document in one gulp.

You should also avoid super-long "sentences", which can easily occur if casual or web-scraped text lacks sentence delimiters, or you are feeding it big tables or gibberish.  The safest way to avoid this issue is to set a parameter limiting the maximum sentence length, such as `-maxLength 100`.

You might want to try out the neural network dependency parser, which scales better to large tasks: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.shtml.

Comment: I cannot avoid long sentences,as i am preparing a dataset. Memory is not a problem as i have 32GB memory.Its just that i a not able to utilize it. Can you tell me how to increase the size of JVM.

Comment: Use 64 bit JVM. Then `java -Xmx12g ...`.

Comment: @ChristopherManning, I'm using CoreNLP, how can I specify `-maxLength` in Java code?

Comment: Use the property a property like `-parse.maxlen 100`; see [ParserAnnotator documentation](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/parse.html).

Comment: @ChristopherManning, I limited the sentence length to 200 chars and increased Java Heap size to 40 Gb (via `-Xmx40g`) but still have sometimes `Parsing of sentences ran out of memory (length=82)`. How can I fix such error? Annotators I use: `tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment`.

Comment: Something is very wrong here. Have you split the document into smaller pieces? Is the right Java process actually getting that memory? This annotation pipeline just shouldn't take a ton of memory. For the 50kB text file [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~manning/xyzzy/cruz-kasich-seven.txt), I can process it in just 1GB of memory without problems with those annotators and this command – does this also work for you? `java -mx1g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators "tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment" -ssplit.newlineIsSentenceBreak two -file cruz-kasich-seven.txt`